# pip3 crashes when installing h5py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, h5py

I am trying to install h5py and execute sudo

> pip3 install h5py

I also tried to install h5py via wheel from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h5py/2.7.0rc2

I have python 3.5 installed. And pip3 then crashes with this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3018, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3004, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3046, in _initialize_master_working_set
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2578, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2152, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2092, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2121, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

I don't think pip3 is broken because I installed a lot with pip3 before.

What can I do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by **not** using sudo to install, but use an [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). I use [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html) personally. Following works fine for me locally.

```
$ mkvirtualenv bla --python=python3 # Random naming
# Env is activated right away
$ pip3 install h5py

Collecting h5py
  Downloading h5py-2.7.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.3MB 340kB/s 
Collecting six (from h5py)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.7 (from h5py)
  Downloading numpy-1.14.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 17.1MB 118kB/s 
Installing collected packages: six, numpy, h5py
Successfully installed h5py-2.7.1 numpy-1.14.0 six-1.11.0
```